# Memcached used for DDOS

Tags: caching, memcached, ddos

Memcached servers can be hijacked for DDoS attacks

- How does it work?
- How can I test my server if it's vulnerable?
- How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a little [post](https://blog.memcachier.com/2018/03/07/memcached-ddos-and-memcachier/) that answers all of your questions. To summarize:

**How does it work?**

In essence an attacker spoofs the IP of a victim and sends UDP requests to a memcached server on behalf of the victim. The attacker basically sends a tiny request to get a large stored value thus flooding the victim.

**Is your server vulnerable?**

Basically, if you are running memcached server version < 1.5.6 which came out on the 27th of February, 2018 and you did not specifically turn off the UDP port, then your memcached server is vulnerable. If you have a firewall that prevents access to UDP port 11211 you are still safe though.

A simple way to test your server is to send a forged `stats` command form a computer that should not have access to your memcached server:

`$ echo -en "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00stats\r\n" | nc -q1 -u <SERVER_IP> 11211`

If you get a response, you are vulnerable.

**How to prevent it?**

You need to start memcached without UDP support (unless you need it). To do so you need to start memcached with the `-U 0` flag. If you use a systemd based system you can add the flag in service file which is located in `/etc/systemd/system/memcached.service`. You need to restart memcached for the changes to take effect (`sudo systemctl restart memcached`).

You should also get your firewall in order. A deny all policy with selective ports that you need being open is generally the way to go.